# How to await http requests in express

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, nodejs-server

I'm trying to get a server to make a series of API calls according to a list of parameters obtained from a form. However, with the async http get method or the npm got library I cannot get my code to await for the responses of the API calls before it tries to render the response. My code looks like this:

```
router.post('/getPolicies', async function(req, res, next){
  let issnList = req.body.issn_list
  issnList = issnList.split(/\r?\n/)
  await getPolicies(issnList);
  res.render("policy", {data:policies})
});
async function getPolicies(issns){
  for (let i = 0; i<issns.length; i++){
      url = "some_url"+ issns[i]
      const {data} = await got.get(url).json();
      constructDataSet(issns[i], data)
  }
}
function constructDataSet (issn, data){
  //...
  //get some information out of a json and construct a new json with data in needed format
}
```

The error I get is "Cannot read properties of undefined" because it's trying to read properties of the "data" json when it hasn't gotten it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are traversing the list synchronously when it should be asynchronous. Below are two diff implementation, the for await loop believe was made available in es6 and the second would be an alternative implementation.

```js
router.post('/getPolicies', async function(req, res, next){
  let issnList = req.body.issn_list
  issnList = issnList.split(/\r?\n/)
  await getPolicies(issnList);
  res.render("policy", {data:policies})
});
// Prefer
async function getPolicies(issns){
  for await (const issns of issns){
      let url = "some_url" + issn;
      const {data} = await got.get(url).json();
      constructDataSet(issns, data)
  }
}

async function getPoliciesV2(issns) {
  await forEach(issns, (issn) => {
    let url = "some_url" + issn; 
    const {data} = await got.get(url).json();
    constructDataSet(issns, data);
  });
  
}
async function forEach(data, callback) {
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    callback(data[i]);
  }
}
function constructDataSet (issn, data){
  //...
  //get some information out of a json and construct a new json with data in needed format
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately after trying to implement both alternatives I keep getting the same error message. Do you know any other alternative that could work?